# Error while trying create new python console project on visual studio 2022

Tags: python, visual-studio-2022

I am using VS 2022, While trying to create new Python Console project, I get this Error message on Error list:

> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not
> found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting
> Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can
> download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

The Output gives me msg:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5):
> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0
> were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks Done building project
> "PythonApplicationTest.pyproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.

I have tried fresh install of the VS on another machine yet still getting the same Error.

Answer (score 0):

It self explnatory, download .NET Microsoft framework, you don not have it installed on your pc that is why

this is the download page
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: I have .net SDK already installed by the VS 2022 application 6.0  4.8 , 4.62,, as well as I just installed 6.0.101 SDK version from MS website, yet I can not access V4.0 as it is out of support,